# ProtoBuff compatibility checker

Tags: protocol-buffers

Planning to use Protocol Buffers for event driven communication across services with Kafka at the heart of these.

I'll maintain the schemas in Github Repo. Changes to the schema would come as Pull Request. In the CI check of the pull request wanted to add a validation to check the backward compatiblity of the Schema change.

Do you know of any open solution to this problem? Or everybody is writing their own compatiblity checker :) ?

Answer (score 4):

Tried out `buf` it is a really nice tooling for using ProtoBuf.

- Enforces API standards with it's `lint` feature

```
buf lint
```

- Maintains compatibility with it's `breaking` feature

```
buf breaking --against ./.git#branch=master
```

- Generates code for you without any headache with its `generate` feature. You just need to create a buf.gen.yaml

```
buf generate
```

Please refer this for more details https://docs.buf.build/tour/generate-code

Answer (score 1):

See: https://github.com/nilslice/protolock

From the README: "Protocol Buffer companion tool. Track your .proto files and prevent changes to messages and services which impact API compatibility."

I discovered the tool as a result of your interesting question. I'd not realized that I would also benefit from this too!

Another, also referenced by Uber's [Prototool](https://github.com/uber/prototool) is [Buf](https://github.com/bufbuild/buf)